# XYZ dataset resampling

Tags: python, matplotlib, binaryfiles

I have large datasets extracted from binary files. They consist in X, Y arrays containing positive decimal coordinates, and other arrays containing values associated to the XY coordinates (Z). I am interested in plotting 2D heatmaps. I have millions of X,Y,Z coordinates in each dataset, so I would like to resample them before generating images.

I could take 1 every Nth data chunk when reading the binary file, but this can affect the result to some extent, as some data are sampled closer than others.

I have tried filling an array and plotting it with imshow(), but it can take a lot of memory, even if most the array is empty. It is also highly limited in size...

I think the most accurate way would be to chose a radius or cell size, and combine/aggregate all the Z data located in each cell (by mean or average), and repeat that to cover the whole X and Y coordinates. However, I don't really see how to do this without calculating the distances between every (X,Y) coordinate set, which can take a lot of time. Are there any ways to perform this kind of operation fast?

I hope I was clear enough!

Comment: How about one of the multivariate interpolators in [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)?

Comment: In particular: `scipy.interpolate.griddata` for resampling on a rectangular grid. If the data is noisy, you can apply a smoothing filter.

Comment: If you are facing memory problems you can split your data file in sub-files allowing some overlapping e.g., data[  0 < x  < 10], data[ 8 < x < 18], data[16 < x < 26], notice the overlapping of a factor of  two. You can create other conditions with your other variables y or z.